# My visual studio script is not working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started game development and got into a problem
whenever I load my Visual Studio code into Unity it says
The refrenced script unknown on this behaviour is missing

This is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VirtualManMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello, World!") ;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I need a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

This may happen is the **file name** does not match the **class name**. Make sure that the file containing this script is also named `VirtualManMovement.cs`

Comment: Hey bro can you explain what is class name?

Comment: It is the name of your class - in this case `VirtualManMovement`. It comes right after the keyword `class`.

Comment: Hey i am sorry to disturb you with stupid questions but where is class writen ?is this where public class is writen?

Comment: @Guts that sounds a bit like you want to stop using Unity and rather watch some c# basics first... and yes in `public class Bla` .. the class name is `Bla` and for Unity to correctly find that component also the file itself needs to have a matching name (in my dumb example that would be `Bla.cs` - where within the editor the extension `.cs` is omitted and it only would show `Bla`)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure in Unity you go to edit -> preferences and see that you have [Unity External tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8cVh.jpg) in Your IDE Selected.
2. Ensure your Code File Name is the same as your Class to prevent confusion.

I was confused as well when I first started. Hopefully, you find this useful